# Internal JSON Structure conflicting with Decodable methods

Tags: json, swift

I have a json structure that looks something like this.

```
    {
      "sneakers" : {
        "brands" : {
          "Adidas" : [ {
            "brand" : "adidas",
            "category" : "lifestyle",
            "colorway" : "Cream White/Cream White/Core White",
            "description" : "First released on April 29, 2017, the Yeezy Boost 350 V2 ‘Cream White’ combines a cream Primeknit upper with tonal cream SPLY 350 branding, and a translucent white midsole housing full-length Boost. Released again in October 2018, this retro helped fulfill Kanye West’s oft-repeated ‘YEEZYs for everyone’ Twitter mantra, as adidas organized the biggest drop in Yeezy history by promising pre-sale to anyone who signed up on the website. Similar to the first release, the ‘Triple White’ 2018 model features a Primeknit upper, a Boost midsole and custom adidas and Yeezy co-branding on the insole.",
            "designer" : "Kanye West",
            "imagesrc" : "https://image.goat.com/crop/1250/attachments/product_template_additional_pictures/images/014/822/695/original/116662_03.jpg.jpeg",
            "maincolor" : "White",
            "name" : "Yeezy Boost 350 V2 'Cream White / Triple White'",
            "nickname" : "Cream White / Triple White",
            "price" : "Buy New - $220",
            "productlink" : "$190YEEZY BOOST 350 V2 'CREAM WHITE / TRIPLE WHITE'",
            "productlinkhref" : "https://www.goat.com/sneakers/yeezy-boost-350-v2-cream-white-cp9366",
            "releasedate" : "2017-04-29",
            "silhouette" : "Yeezy Boost 350",
            "technology" : "Boost",
            "web-scraper-order" : "1554084922-147",
            "webscraperstarturl" : "https://www.goat.com/sneakers"
          }, {
            "brand" : "adidas",
            "category" : "running",
            "colorway" : "Footwear White/Footwear White/Footwear White",
            "description" : "The adidas Ultra Boost 4.0 'Triple White' launched in November 2016. The fourth edition of adidas’ performance runner features a blank-canvas aesthetic, featuring crisp white on the shoe’s Primeknit upper, laces and supportive midfoot cage. A bit of shine comes courtesy of the silver Ultra Boost branding on the heel stabilizer, while the black finish on the Continental Rubber outsole offers a lone shot of contrast.",
            "designer" : "Ben Herath",
            "imagesrc" : "https://image.goat.com/crop/1250/attachments/product_template_additional_pictures/images/010/222/174/original/264258_08.jpg.jpeg",
            "maincolor" : "White",
            "name" : "UltraBoost 4.0 'Triple White'",
            "nickname" : "Triple White",
            "price" : "Buy New - $180 $110",
            "productlink" : "$90ULTRABOOST 4.0 'TRIPLE WHITE'",
            "productlinkhref" : "https://www.goat.com/sneakers/ultra-boost-4-0-triple-white-bb6168",
            "releasedate" : "2017-11-16",
            "silhouette" : "UltraBoost",
            "technology" : "Boost",
            "web-scraper-order" : "1554084884-8",
            "webscraperstarturl" : "https://www.goat.com/sneakers"
          }
    ]
  }
}
```

I am trying to decode this json structure using swift 4 decodable and it is giving me a little bit of trouble.

The current struct(s) that I have for decoding the values are as so

```
import Foundation
import RealmSwift


struct Sneaker: Decodable {
    let sneakers : Sneakers

}

struct Sneakers: Decodable {
    let brands: Shoe
}



struct Shoe: Decodable {
    let adidas: [SneakerInfo]
    let nike: [SneakerInfo]
    let airjordan: [SneakerInfo]
    let vans: [SneakerInfo]
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case adidas = "Adidas"
        case nike = "Nike"
        case airjordan = "Air Jordan"
        case vans = "Vans"
    }
}


struct SneakerInfo: Decodable {
    let brand, category, colorway, description: String
    let designer: String
    let imagesrc: String
    let maincolor, name, nickname, price: String
    let productlink: String
    let productlinkhref: String
    let releasedate, silhouette, technology, webscraperorder: String
    let webscraperstarturl: String
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case brand, category, colorway, description, designer, imagesrc, maincolor, name, nickname, price, productlink, productlinkhref, releasedate, silhouette, technology,webscraperorder,webscraperstarturl
    }
}
```

But I keep getting an error in regards to the structure

> Expected to decode Array but found a dictionary instead

However I know dictionaries don't conform to decodable can anyone see what's wrong based on my JSON structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this

```
struct Sneaker: Codable {
    let sneakers: Sneakers
}

struct Sneakers: Codable {
    let brands: Shoe
}

struct Shoe: Codable {
    let adidas: [Adida]

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case adidas = "Adidas"
    }
}
struct Adida: Codable {
    let brand, category, colorway, description: String
    let designer: String
    let imagesrc: String
    let maincolor, name, nickname, price: String
    let productlink: String
    let productlinkhref: String
    let releasedate, silhouette, technology, webScraperOrder: String
    let webscraperstarturl: String

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case brand, category, colorway, description, designer, imagesrc, maincolor, name, nickname, price, productlink, productlinkhref, releasedate, silhouette, technology
        case webScraperOrder = "web-scraper-order"
        case webscraperstarturl
    }
}
```

Comment: trying now give me a second

Comment: I mean there is more than one type of shoe. There are addidas, nike, jordan, vans 
 and under each . of those you see a list of shoes how would i generalize that

Comment: you need key for each  look at Shoe struct it contain adidas, you need to add the others to be able to decode, ( decoders must have keys ) to be able to decode them

Comment: okay let me try that right now also why did you use codable instead of decodablw

Comment: Codable is only typealias for ( decodable & encodable )

Comment: Umm it is saying certain keys can't be found that I know are there let me show what i have

Comment: says _JSONKey(stringValue: "Index 3", intValue: 3)], debugDescription: "No value associated with key CodingKeys(stringValue: \"description\", intValue: nil) (\"description\").", underlyingError: nil))

Comment: in adida struct make the properties optional String? , etc instead of string

Comment: thank you this worked I need some practice with JSON this took me entirely too long

Comment: acpt answer ^^   gl

Comment: `Adida` — is semantically bad name for the class. Also instead of `Shoe` type `[String: Adida]`(`Adida` still to be renamed) should be used, because I'm pretty sure there would be more than just `Adidas` brand.